# Memory Leaks in Get / Set LINQ BindingList<T> Property

Tags: c#, linq, memory-leaks

We have memory leaks in a program that we are trying to stop.

We have isolated the form, and this form has several [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) Properties.

Currently, these properties are written in the following format:

```
private BindingList<DataModel1> _dataModel1List;

public BindingList<DataModel1> DataModel1List
{
    get
    {
        var temp = from r in dbo_datamodel1 orderby r.label select r;
        _dataModel1List= ((IListSource)temp).GetList() as BindingList<DataModel1>;
        return _dataModel1List;
    }
    set
    {
        _dataModel1List= value;
    }
}
```

I am no expert on the [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) class, but it looks to me like we are getting a new set of data every time we call this.

Further, if we get the data using the *getter* and then set it later using the *setter*, it looks like we are going to overwrite what we had before with the incoming `value`.

Could this be the source of our memory leaks? I count 52 of these [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) properties on this one form.

If I were to rewrite it like below, would that fix the memory leak or cause problems with the [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx)? I am particularly concerned with the *Clear()* call in the *setter*.

```
private BindingList<DataModel1> _dataModel1List;

public BindingList<DataModel1> DataModel1List
{
    get
    {
        if (_dataModel1List== null)
        {
            _dataModel1List= new BindingList<DataModel1>(
                (from r in dbo_datamodel1
                 orderby r.name
                 select r).ToList());
        }
        return _dataModel1List;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_dataModel1List!= null)
        {
            _dataModel1List.Clear();
        }
        _dataModel1List= value;
    }
}
```

Since there are so many of these properties that could be contributing to the memory leak, I want to make sure I am not going to cause problems before I make this change all over.

Comment: Use a memory profiler, it will tell you where your memory leeks are. There is a free one built in to Visual Studio or you can often get free trial periods of commercial ones (I personally like [DotMemory by JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/), they give you a 5 day trial)

Comment: We have one. That's how we know the memory leak is coming from this form. Particularly, it is coming from the data bindings. I just don't know what is leaking or how to fix it.

Comment: Do you really need a `BindingList`? Is it possible to switch over to a `ObserveableCollection` If you don't use [`BindingList<T>.ListChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132742(v=vs.110).aspx) to detect child `INotifyPropertyChange` fireings I would recommend switching.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I could look into `ObserveableCollection`. All of the other forms that call this one are wired to accept the `BindingList`, so changing the signature would have greater impact.

Comment: Does your `DataModel1` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @IvanStoev - no, these data models are just dumb classes of `int` and `string` values.

Comment: Then I don't see any issue with the `BindingList` content. But you are right for the weird property getter, and calling `Clear` at setter does not hurt, so why don't you try the suggested rewrite and see.